# How to tokenize a string with percentages?

Tags: c++, c++11, tokenize

My purpose is to tokenize the following input string `%08%04root%08%03KEY%08%05site2%08%11ksk-1483008950879%08%07ID-CERT` in this way:

```
4root
3KEY
5site2
11ksk-1483008950879
7ID-CERT
```

Then I tried the following approach:

```
char_separator<char> sepSig("%08");    
boost::tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokenSig(inputString, sepSig);   
BOOST_FOREACH (const string& t, tokenSig)
    log << "Token: " << t << std::endl;
```

Unfortunately, all the items '8' are catched, with the following division:

```
Token: 4root //OK
Token: 3KEY  //OK
Token: 5site2 //OK
Token: 11ksk-14 
Token: 3
Token: 95
Token: 79
Token: 7ID-CERT //OK
```

Then I need a way to differentiate the item `%08` from `8`. I tried also the separators `\08` and `\x08`, but in this way the token is the same of the whole string.

Comment: What kind of format is that? It resembles URI encoding.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Show your definition of `tokenizer`

Comment: It should be Uri encoding, yes.

About the tokenizer, I just included <boost/tokenizer.hpp> following the suggestion of another answer. Then I wrote the definition in the question

Comment: `sepSig("%08")` means "split on every `%`, or `0`, or `8`", not on `"%08"`. Boost doc says it's just like `strtok`.

Comment: If it's URI encoded, then the values are `root`, `KEY` and `site2` which makes more sense. `%08` is simply a representation for hexadecimal ASCII character 8, which is a backspace character.

Comment: Those are not "percentages"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::char_separator` treats *any* of the characters as separators.  I can't see a `string_separator` - you could write your own, or just replace every occurance of `"%08"` with `"\t"`, and then separate on `\t`.